# Why doesn't django take my language file into account?

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, gettext

I followed the whole documentation about text translation, but django doesn't take my `.mo` file into account.

Some facts:

- I created a `conf/locale/` folder at the root of my project
- `django.po` was generated successfully with `django-admin.py makemessages -l fr`
- `django.mo` was generated successfully with `django-admin.py compilemessages`

So my folder structure is:

```
project/
  site/
  locale/
    fr/
      LC_MESSAGES/
        django.mo
        django.po
```

- In `settings.py`, I have set `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'`
- My browser correctly sends `Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;`
- `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` shows `fr` from my views

But I get nothing translated... How to make django take these files into account ?

---

### Edit

Adding `/home/www/project/locale` to `settings.LOCALE_PATHS` works. However, Django should find this path by itself, and I don't like using absolute paths. What happens here ?

Comment: Can you maybe show us how you're trying to translate something in your code?

Comment: It doesn't come from the way I translate things (see my edit), but if it matters: `_("text")` in views (with lazy translation) and `{% trans "text" %}` in templates.

Comment: Just want to make sure you calling the lazy variant of `gettext` when using `_`: `gettext_lazy`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**LOCALE_PATHS**

Django looks for translation files in 3 locations by default:

- `LOCALE_PATHS/(language)/LC_MESSAGES/django.(po|mo)`
- `$APPPATH/locale/(language)/LC_MESSAGES/django.(po|mo)`
- `$PYTHONPATH/django/conf/locale/(language)/LC_MESSAGES/django.(po|mo)`

LOCALE_PATHS only need to be used if your translation files aren't in your app directories or on the PYTHON_PATH.

An example of LOCALE_PATHS in settings.py

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/home/www/project/conf/locale', # replace with correct path here
)
```

**MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES**

Add `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py

**LANGUAGES**

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', 'Français'),
)
```

Comment: [This documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) says that Django search for translations in `$APPPATH/locale/<language>/LC_MESSAGES/django.(po|mo)`. I shouldn't have to add this line. LocaleMiddleware is correctly added.

Comment: based on your folder structure, is "project" a Django app or the root of your Django project?

Comment: Ok, your comment lead my to the solution: Django searches in `$APPPATH`, which is not the `project` path but the `site` directory. Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it ? Thanks ;)